# How to retrieve specific data from firebase realtime database when data changed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating the function that the user can track the driver's location. I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude only when the driver's location change.

Database structure

[Firebase Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHwO1.jpg)

driver.java(added setter and getter)

```
public class driver {
    private String Email, BusID, Carplate, PhoneNo, Password, Latitude, Longitude;

    public driver(String Email, String BusID, String Carplate, String PhoneNo, String Password,
                  String Latitude, String Longitude){
        this.Email = Email;
        this.BusID = BusID;
        this.Carplate = Carplate;
        this.PhoneNo = PhoneNo;
        this.Password = Password;
        this.Latitude = Latitude;
        this.Longitude = Longitude;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }
    public String getBusID() {
        return BusID;
    }
    public void setBusID(String busID) {
        BusID = busID;
    }
    public String getCarplate() {
        return Carplate;
    }
    public void setCarplate(String carplate) {
        Carplate = carplate;
    }
    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return PhoneNo;
    }
    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        PhoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        Password = password;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }
    public String getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
```

Java

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Driver");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                driver loc = dataSnapshot.getValue(driver.class);
                if (loc != null) {
                    Log.d("Location", "" +loc.getLatitude()+ ", " +loc.getLongitude());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

How I can get the data from the database?
Please help me. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you haven't made any attempt to use the DataSnapshot as described in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks for your reply@DougStevenson. I tried that it is worked but my data is null and I found this ```W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for YwYeegL8MjPU5J6RtK7JXNazc9Y2 found on class com.example.publictransporttracker.driver```. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to this:

```
public class Driver {
    private String email, busID, carplate, phoneNo, password, latitude, longitude;

    /** No-arg constructor (takes no arguments). */
    public Driver() {
    }

    public Driver(String email, String busID, String carplate, String phoneNo, String password,
                  String latitude, String longitude){
        this.email = email;
        this.busID = busID;
        this.carplate = carplate;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.password = password;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
```

You need to follow the [java bean convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), then when adding data, create a new `Driver` object and use it inside of `setValue()`:

```
Driver dirver = new Driver(email, busID, carplate, phoneNo, password,latitude,longitude);
mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(user);
```

Then to retrieve the data, do the following:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Driver");

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  Driver driver = dataSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Thanks @Peter Haddad, Your solution is worked but I can't get the value for longitude and latitude on the database when using getter. And I found the log ```W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for YwYeegL8MjPU5J6RtK7JXNazc9Y2 found on class com.example.publictransporttracker.driver```. How can I solve it?

Comment: add setters and getters to ur class, forgot to add that in android studio you can write click and generate getters and setters automatically

Comment: its important to change the name of the variables as in my answer or it cannot map the object to the database, so change them to camelCase and then generate getters and setters

Comment: Thank you for your answer@Peter Haddad, I have solved my problem.