# Retrieve specific fields from Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this json file inside a Realtime Firebase DB.

`{
    {"tag1" : "data_a", "tag2" : "data_b", ...}
    {"tag1" : "data_c", "tag2" : "data_d", ...}
     ...
}`

I have to retrieve all *data_x* which matches whatever the user types in a certain search bar. Think of it as the search bar in Spotify or SoundCloud where you search for artists, individual songs as well as albums. I am using Kotlin.

Comment: Have u tried the answer?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but i was building it on pure Kotlin. So no. But  I'll convert this snippet. Thanks.

Comment: Well how would I know that you are using kotlin if you didn't show any code nor did you use the tag kotlin 

Comment: I am sorry. But I really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dbRef.orderByChild("tag1").equalTo("data_a").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      //here you will get the data
   }

    @Override
   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {    
         throw databaseError.toException();
       }
   });
```

You can use a query `equalTo()` to check if a specific tag is equal to the value that the user wrote in the search and then retrieve the sibling data.

Comment: can you explain what is need to be put in onDataChange? Could be something like variableToSave= dataSnapShot.toString()?

Comment: @RodParedes Sorry didn't understand what do you mean? But here the you are creating an anonymous class that implements the `ValueEventListener` so you have to override both methods `onDataChange` and `onCancelled`. `onDataChange` will listen to any data change from the database, so you can just retrieve the data there. If you are wondering what to add inside the method you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60212826/how-to-retrieve-specific-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-when-data-changed